# Select rows from a MySQL JSON column that meets a condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am trying to select rows from a JSON table column (in MySQL 5.7.3) that meet a certain condition. And yes, using a JSON column rather than just creating a separate MySQL table is intentional. Consider the following MySQL table:

**Table: Record**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Record (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    foo VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'bar',
    data JSON DEFAULT NULL <--- WE POPULATE THIS COLUMN WITH DATA
)
```

**Create a 'Record' with the following data**

```json
[{
    "id": 1,
    "timestamp": 1623671469
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "timestamp": 1623672921
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "timestamp": 1623872921
}]
```

**Result**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Record [id,foo,data]                  |
+---------------------------------------+
| [1, 'bar', [{"id":1,"timestamp":162..]|
+---------------------------------------+
```

Now we want to select rows in the **data** column where **id** is **larger than 2**

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].id") as result
FROM
    Record
WHERE
    JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].id") > 2 <--- does not work, returns [1,2,3] for any number
```

Similarly, we want to be able to return the rows that have a timestamp between **timestamp1** and **timestamp2**.

Is it possible to select only those rows that meet a condition using JSON_EXTRACT (in MySQL 5.7.3)?

Comment: Just one more reason why the JSON datatype shouldn't be used. This is easy if you normalize the schema.

Comment: *Create a 'Record' with the following data .. Result* - give this as INSERT INTO statement. *Now we want to select **rows in the data** column where id is larger than 2* - this means that you must parse an array in `data` to separate objects, one object per row, firstly. And then - check them separately.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose to put this data in JSON format instead of making a normal table with colums `id`, `timestamp`?

Comment: @Barmar, the JSON column adds flexibility for cases when additional columns are not known to you up front, (e.g. when user input should add to the existing columns) rather than creating columns in the table to cover every case

Comment: You can do that with an attribute-value table.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think there's a way to filter JSON based on a condition like this. `JSON_EXTRACT` returns all the values, and you're comparing that array with a single number.